# ShrinkWrap's .addAsResource in Arquillian's persistance guide

Tags: jboss-arquillian

I am studying Arquillian platform. I am following 

http://arquillian.org/guides/testing_java_persistence/#write_the_test

at a certain point of the guide, you can read:

> "We define the Persistence Unit in a test-persistence.xml file that’s
>   corresponding to the target container. ShrinkWrap takes this file from
>   the classpath and puts it into its standard location within the
>   archive."

```
.addAsResource("test-persistence.xml", "META-INF/persistence.xml")
```

You can see this command in

> src/test/java/org/arquillian/example/GamePersistenceTest.java
>   that is in the upper part of the page.

So my question is: is this piece of the guide a simply explanation of that code line, or is something you have to add into another class to do the example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it's just explaining that line, it means you need to add this file onto classpath with `ShrinkWrap` in order to  make the persistence work.

Comment: for file(s?), do you mean "test-persistence.xml", "META-INF/persistence.xml" ?

Comment: File. This means that Arquillian will take file `src/test/resources/test-persistence.xml` and puts it inside test.war to the META-INF/ folder.